# Offline speech recognition in custom android OS

Tags: android

I am building a app for a custom android OS, which is a embedded system of a device.

I build the app on a HTC one M9 and the speech recognition is working perfectly, but since I run the same APK on my embedded system, it crash and show the error code as below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
```

After some research, my system can run the voice recognition after installed the google app "Voice Search".

In my HTC one M9, I can download offline speech data for offline use as follow:

"Setting -> Language & Keyboard -> Voice input -> Enhanced Google services ->  Offline speech recognition"

But when I go to the same page in my system, "Offline speech recognition" is disappear and I am not able to download any offline speech data to use.

My system need to work offline, what should I do to show the selection? Or is there any method to use the offline voice speech recognition?

Comment: You can try to use some differen speech recognition api, like Sphinx: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download

Comment: @Christopher thanks, I try to use the cmusphinx this two day and I am not sure is it so sensitive or something, it keep return the hypothesis result even I said nothing, is there any setting to reduce the background noisy?